# Why does -std=c11 with gcc hide popen in stdio.h?

Tags: c, popen

I want to use popen. It is in stdio.h. I include that, but the compiler doesn't see it with 
-std=c11. It does compile without -std=c11.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   popen("ls *","r");
}
```

> gcc -std=c11 popen_test.c

popen_test.c: In function ‘main’: 

popen_test.c:5:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘popen’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

> ```
> popen("ls *","r");
> ^~~~~
> ```

It is hidden in stdio.h with

```
#ifdef __USE_POSIX2
```

The man page says it is available if:

> _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 2  || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ 
>   _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE

Comment: `popen` is not part of standard C.

Comment: @melpomene Can you turn -std=c11 on and off in the source code?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Or maybe a better question: What are you trying to achieve by specifying `-std=c11`?

Comment: @melpomene I want all the features of C11

Comment: Well, e.g. `-std=gnu11` would give you that plus all GNU extensions.

Answer (score 1):

`popen` is not part of C. To get it, you need to enable it with a [feature test macro](https://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros) before including anything.

The simplest way to do it is with a `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top (or with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in your compiler invocation).

compiles with -std=c11:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   popen("ls *","r");
}
```

Comment: Does -std=c11 mean "don't allow anything that isn't part of C11"? I was hoping for "allow anything that is part of C11".

Comment: @Scooter I'd say it's more like that calling `gcc` without a specific standards gives you some extra gnu stuff (`-std=gnu11` or whatever your compiler defaults to). `-std=c11` disables it so that the identifiers that the C standard says should belong to you aren't taken.

Comment: @Scooter `int popen; int main(void) { return popen; }` is a valid C11 program, but it would conflict with the `popen` function.